# SSRS - Report Heading to display in every page for Dynamic Table

Tags: reporting-services

I have a RDLC report which is having a Table with different rows having different groups. Also the Column will be displayed dynamically in runtime based on the fields fetched from the Database. How to get the Report Page Header displayed for this Matrix in every page?

So far I have performed below steps:

1) Create table and delete all but 1 column.

2) Add another row above header and delete details row.

3) add matrix in 2nd row and title in the first row.

4) Center aligned the title and set RepeatOnNewPage property to true

5) Set KeepWithGroup property to After and FixData to true

6) Also set Repeat header rows on each page to true

But the header is not displaying in the Next Page, instead it is taking as a single page and displays at the right end top corner. It is not taking as 2 pages to display seperately.

Comment: Hey there & welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is incomplete and has little chances to get answered as is. Please read the **[How-To-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** article & edit your question adding more information. Let's start with some snippets that you've worked on regarding the matter! (if you need help with this, read up on how to create a **[Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**)

Comment: @iamdanchiv - do you know anything about SSRS? A snippet of code?

Comment: @HannoverFist my bad homie. Thanks! Thought code-less stuff was intended for META sites. Keep that same energy! ;)

Comment: Is this, [How to repeat table group header on every page in SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60369354/how-to-repeat-table-group-header-on-every-page-in-ssrsrdlc-report-when-outputt/60369355#60369355), what you were looking for?